# How do I verify that a protected method in a parent class is run?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, verify

I am trying to capture a response string for a child controller class when the method that sends the response exists in the parent class.

I have tried mocking the parent class and verifying that the method gets called but since the method is referenced in class the verify is not picking up the that the messaging method is being called. How can I verify that this method is called so I can capture the response content?

This is an abstract version of my code but it explains the situation I believe.

```
public class AbstractController {
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletResponse response, 
         String forward, HttpMethod method, MessageRequest request){
        //the method process request then sends response back using this
        sendJsonResponse(response,HttpStatus.CREATED,messageResponse);
    }

    protected  sendJsonResponse(HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus status, String msg){
        //send the message 
    }
}

public class StartController extends AbstractController {
    public void start(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, HttpSevletResponse response){
        handleRequest(reponse,"actor1",HttpMethod.POST,new MessageRequest(arg1,arg2,arg3));
    }
}

public class TestStartController{
    // several mocked services declared here
    @Test
    public void testStart(){

        String expectResult = "some string";

        when(mockservc.sendMessageDeeper(~)).thenReturn("raw response"); 

        ArgumentCaptor<String> bodyCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        StartController sc = new StartController(); 

        sc.start(anyString(),anyString(),anyString,(),responseMock);

        verify(mockServc).sendMessageDeeper(~);

        //this is the method that I need to make sure runs since the method below is 
        //statically reference it is not registering being executed by the verify need help here             
        verify(abstractControllerMock).sendJsonReponse(same(responeMock),eq(HttpStatus.CREATED),bodyCaptor.capture()); 

        assertJsonEquals(expectResult,bodyCaptor.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your protected method DO something? Then why not check that? For example, if it does something to the response, check that something has been done to the response... This way you can indirectly test your method.

Comment: I am having trouble writing the response's content to a string. Is there a tutorial page out there for this? All the questions answered here on how do not really help me, which is why I went this seemingly easier route.

Comment: responseMock seems to be a mock, you can simply verify that the appropriate methods have been called on that?

Comment: I guess I need help with my mockito test set up. I am trying to verify that sendJsonResponse() above is called that way I can capture the message content which is the real purpose of this test. However, since sendJsonResponse is a helper-ish method in the parent class, I am junping through hoops to try verifying it. The way I try verifying in my example above never gets triggered thus my tests fail. Originally, the method was private but I made is protected to open it to the test class through the child class. Still it is not getting 'detected'.

Comment: Mockito cannot, afaik, check protected methods. You would need PowerMock for that (and I don't suggest it). As I said, to me, it seems, that you've got the mock object for the `HttpServletResponse` that will go into the method (and be manipulated there) - `responseMock` (btw, anyString() is not intended to be used in calling stuff, just for matching). So you should be able to verify that the public methods of responseMock were called to write the response somewhere... Isn't that enough to ensure that your protected method is tested - test the result?

Comment: No I am not testing the response, I am testing the content of the response. The handleRequest does some json transformation that wasn't necessary to to say as it was background. I am trying to do it through the sendJsonResponse() as it was the last method "open" before I would have to write several new classes to filter and read the HttpServletResponse (too messy for a test).